# Difference in Python thread.join() between Python 3.7 and 3.8

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a small Python program that behaves differently in Python 3.7 and Python 3.8. I'm struggling to understand why. The [#threading changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#threading) for Python 3.8 does not explain this.

Here's the code:

```
import time
from threading import Event, Thread


class StoppableWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableWorker, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = False
        self._stop_event = Event()
    

    def join(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._stop_event.set()
        print("join called")
        super(StoppableWorker, self).join(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        while not self._stop_event.is_set():
            time.sleep(1)
            print("hi")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = StoppableWorker()
    t.start()
    print("main done.")
```

When I run this in Python 3.7.3 (Debian Buster), I see the following output:

```
python test.py 
main done.
join called
hi
```

The program exits on its own. I don't know why `join()` is called.
From the [daemon documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) of 3.7:

> The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.

But clearly the thread should be still alive.

When I run this in Python 3.8.6 (Arch), I get the expected behavior. That is, the program keeps running:

```
python test.py
main done.
hi
hi
hi
hi
...
```

The [daemon documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) for 3.8 states the same as 3.7: The program should not exit unless all non-daemon threads have joined.

Can someone help me understand what's going on, please?

Comment: If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signaling mechanism such as an Event

Comment: Re, "I don't know why `join()` is called." Can you not set a breakpoint, and find out who called it? Or, maybe easier, replace the `print("join called")` with a statement that will raise an error and dump the stack.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is a proper use of join, as in one could complain that Python is wrong to use-or-not-use it like this. The purpose of ``join`` is to *wait* for the thread to end – not to signal to the thread that it *should* end. Which is exactly how Python uses it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an undocumented change in the behavior of threading `_shutdown()` from Python version 3.7.3 to 3.7.4.

Here's how I found it:

To trace the issue, I first used the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack) package to find out who `join()`s the thread in the Python 3.7.3 runtime. I modified the `join()` function to get some output:

```
...
    def join(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._stop_event.set()
        c = threading.current_thread()
        print(f"join called from thread {c}")
        print(f"calling function: {inspect.stack()[1][3]}")
        super(StoppableWorker, self).join(*args, **kwargs)
...
```

When executing with Python 3.7.3, this prints:

```
main done.
join called from thread <_MainThread(MainThread, stopped 139660844881728)>
calling function: _shutdown
hi
```

So the `MainThread`, which is already stopped, invokes the `join()` method. The function responsible in the `MainThread` is `_shutdown()`.

From the [CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/threading.py#L1263) for Python 3.7.3 for `_shutdown()`, lines 1279-1282:

```
    t = _pickSomeNonDaemonThread()
    while t:
        t.join()
        t = _pickSomeNonDaemonThread()
```

*That code invokes `join()` on all non-daemon threads when the `MainThread` exits!*

That implementation was [changed in Python 3.7.4](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.4/Lib/threading.py#L1275).

To verify these findings I built Python 3.7.4 from source. It indeed behaves differently. It keeps the thread running as expected and the `join()` function is not invoked.

This is apparently not documented in the [release notes of Python 3.7.4](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/) nor in the [changelog of Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#threading).

-- EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments by MisterMiyagi, one might argue that extending the `join()` function and using it for signaling termination is not a proper use of `join()`. IMHO that is up to taste. It should, however, be documented that in Python 3.7.3 and before, `join()` is invoked by the Python runtime on system exit, while with the change to `3.7.4` this is no longer the case. If properly documented, it would explain this behavior from the get-go.

Comment: Re, "It should...be documented that...join() is invoked by the Python runtime." I disagree. There is no reason why that should be documented. A call to `t.join()` is not suposed to have any effect on thread `t`. When you override `t.join()` so that it _does_ affect `t`, that's not just a matter of taste.  You broke the contract: You created a thread object that does not behave the way the system expects thread objects to behave, and then you gave it to the system and asked the system to run it for you (i.e., you called `t.start()`)

Comment: Agree with @SolomonSlow. The 3.7.4 change per comment now mimics Thread.join() instead of calling it directly likely due to issues like this...overriding join() with unexpected functionality.

Comment: See my answer for the bugfix doc that may explain this 3.7.4 change.

Answer (score 2):

What's New only lists new features.  This changes looks to me like a bug fix.
https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html has a `changelog` link near the top. Given the research in @Felix's answer, we should look at bugfixes released in 3.7.4.
https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-7-4-release-candidate-1

This might be the issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue36402
bpo-36402: Fix a race condition at Python shutdown when waiting for threads. Wait until the Python thread state of all non-daemon threads get deleted (join all non-daemon threads), rather than just wait until non-daemon Python threads complete.